# cakephp 3 edit user username and password - Unable to find table class for current entity

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp 3.5 (ran the update today) to make my first non tutorial web application. I am trying to set up my app so that I can edit my users account details (username and password).
I am not sure what I have done, but I cannot actually access my edit.ctp (view) while I am logged in. I keep getting a "Unable to find table class for current entity" error.

what I am aiming to ultimately do is enable to the users to be able to edit their username (which is an email address) and change their password when they would like.

Could someone please help me workout where I have gone wrong, and why I keep getting the "Unable to find table class for current entity" error and what I can do to fix it.
I have read as many of the relevant articles on this as I can find. I have tried various "isAuthorised" function versions and I keep getting the same error so I am sure it is something that I just don't know what to look for.

Below is my code:

```
The User.php file:

<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * User Entity.
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $role
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $created
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $activity_date
 * @property bool $terms_of_service
 * @property bool $paid
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $paid_date
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $paid_until
 * @property bool $verified
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\Agent[] $agents
 */
class User extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
    ];
    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}

The UsersTable.php file:
<?php 
namespace App\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Entity\User;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Users Model
 *
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\HasMany $Agents
 */
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('username');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Agents', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
         $validator
            ->notEmpty('username','Please supply your email address')
            ->add('username', 'valid', ['rule'=>'email']);

        $validator
            ->notEmpty('password','Please supply your password');

        $validator
            ->notEmpty('role','Please select your account type')
            ->add('role','inList',[
                'rule' => ['inList',['agent','buyer']],
                'message' => 'Please select a valid role'
            ]);

        $validator
            ->add('terms_of_service', 'valid', ['rule' => 'boolean'])
            ->notEmpty('terms_of_service','You must agree to the terms of service to register');

        return $validator;
    }
    public function isOwnedBy($userId)
    {
        return $this->exists(['id' => $userId]);
    }
    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
        return $rules;
    }
}

The relevant pieces UsersController.php file:

<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Event\Event;
//use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Auth->allow(['signup','logout']);
        $this->Auth->deny(['index']);

    }
    // The owner of an user can edit and delete it
    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        if (in_array($this->request->action, ['edit', 'delete','view'])) {
            if ($this->Users->isOwnedBy($user['id'])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]); 
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your account has been edited.'));
                return $this->redirect(['controller','Users','action' => 'edit']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

The AppController.php file

<?php
/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     0.2.9
 * @license   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     *
     * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading components.
     *
     * e.g. `$this->loadComponent('Security');`
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            /*'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
                ]
            ],*/
            'authorize' => 'Controller',
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Properties',
                'action' => 'myproperties'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => '',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer(),
            //'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view that page.',
        ]);
        // Allow the display action so our pages controller continues to work
        $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
    }
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view','logout','search']);
    }
    /**
     * Before render callback.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Event\Event $event The beforeRender event.
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
        $this -> set('user', $this -> Auth -> user());
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
    $childClass = get_called_class();

    if(method_exists($childClass, '_isAuthorized'))
        return $childClass::_isAuthorized($user, $this -> request);

    return static::_isAuthorized($user, $request);
    }
    static public function _isAuthorized($user, $request)
    {

        // Admin can access every action
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
            return true;
        }       
        // Default deny
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: David, is there a reason you are using the isAuthorized that way? If your child has an isAuthorized, it should call that. You don't have to make your app controller call your child class IsAuthorized function.

Comment: @chrisShick No... using it that way was in one of the examples I looked at while trying to solve my problem. My previous isAuthorised looked like this: `public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
  if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }`

Comment: You could also try sth simple like [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) to manage your role based access. No need to hack around in the controllers then.

Comment: Thanks @mark, I shall give that a try.

Comment: But in your example it looks like you also need some row based access. So then it won't work out.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by row based access? I have discovered that the problem occurs when I use `$this->Form->create($user)` in the edit.ctp file, if I remove the `$user` variable the form is created, but without my values.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that in your `AppController` in  `beforeRender` method you have this..

```
    $this -> set('user', $this -> Auth -> user());
```

That's mean you will share the current user logged with all controllers and actions..

And also notice that in your edit action in Users Controller you also  called a variable `$user` and you send it to the view by the `set` ...

So that is the source of  your problem and that's why if you change the name by `users` it works !! It seems there is a conflict between the `$user` sent in `beforeRender` method and the `$user` sent in your edit action in Users Controller

Comment: Ooohh, I had a similar problem, and that's precisely why. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after lots of trial and error I have solved the problem. It is a simple fix, although I do not know why it works... so if someone could explain that would be great: I changed the `$user` variable in my controller file's edit function to `$users` as well as the `$user` variable in the edit.ctp file to `$users` and hey presto it worked.